# Почему в try работает только первая строка кода, а остальные нет?

Tags: python

Имеется много картинок с форматом `.png`, каждый набор лежит в своей папке. Хочу в цикле пройтись по всем папкам и все картинки перевести в формат `.jpg`. Но почемуто дальше первой строки в try код не работает. try сделал потому что некоторые картинки не читаются и выдают исключение.

```
for file in glob.glob("/content/Cyrillic/*/*.png"):
  try:  
    im = Image.open(file)
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    rgb_im.save("png", "jpg")
    print(file)
  except:
    continue
```

Comment: Какое именно исключение?

Comment: Ну а если вы хотите пропустить картинки, которые не читаются, то логично в try-except заворачивать только код чтения картинки, а не вообще всё подряд

Comment: `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/content/Cyrillic/У/58bf15f5df53d.png'`

Comment: Оставьте внутри try-except только первую строчку (ну ещё можно добавить `im.load()` для надёжности), а всё остальное оставьте после except, чтобы не перехватывать неожиданные исключения

Comment: Если так сделать в except получается исключение `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'convert'`

Comment: А это намекает, что вы показали код не целиком и где-то меняете переменную `im`

Comment: Ну значит `PIL` не может распознать формат этих файлов. А так они открываются каким-нибудь редактором графическим?

Comment: В стандартном приложении Windows все картинки открываются

Comment: Странно. Ну тогда это проблемы с `PIL` в любом случае, а не с питоном. А версия `PIL` свежая? Странно это всё. Ну попробуйте другими какими-то библиотеками пооткрывать эти картинки по одной. Тут только разбираться вручную.